How to replace or update the routerConfig on flutter?
How should I update or replace the Material.router routerConfig based on  user role? Example I have this
loginRoute = GoRouter(...);
adminRouts = GoRouter(...);
memberRoutes = GoRouter(...);

MaterialApp.router()
  routerConfig: loginRoute,
);

Now after successfull login I want to replace the routerConfig to  either adminRoutes or memberRoutes?

check RoutingConfig

@pskink yes i mean I already read it, but I dont know how to update routerConfig

"but I dont know how to update routerConfig" - as the docs say: "This is typically used with GoRouter.routingConfig to create a go router with dynamic routing config.", so did you use GoRouter.routingConfig? if so, whats not working?

Yes I did create the and its working the loginroute my problem is how should I write so i can change the MaterialApp routerConfig from  loginRoute to memberRoute. sorry Im just started learning flutter, and I cant find example on google

what have you passed in GoRouter.routingConfig as a required routingConfig parameter?

I create a new instance of GoRouter with navigationrail and navigationBar and i didn't touch the routingConfig. Then I set the GoRouter instange to MaterialApp.routerConfig

again: you used GoRouter.routingConfig constructor (and not GoRouter), right? so what have you passed as a required routingConfig parameter? what type of variable have you used?

@pskink thanks for the help, i was able to solve  it using block and GoRouter

you are still using "static" GoRouter(routes, ....) constructor, they created a "dynamic" version  GoRouter.routingConfig for cases like yours, the docs say: "Creates a GoRouter with a dynamic RoutingConfig."

could you give me example how to properly do that, I'm sorry because I'm lost

it is in the official documentation, type ctrl-F Dynamic RoutingConfig

I was able to solve it using bloc, when I trigger the login it will change the appropriate routes.
First setup the routes
// login routes has login and register
final loginRoute = GoRouter(routes:[...], ...);

// admin routes has routes if the user is already logged in
final adminRoute = GoRouter(routes:[...], ...);

Then I have a Cubit that will notify if the authentiaction status changed.
class RouteCubit extends Cubit<GoRouter> {
  // I  use authRouter as the default routes
  RouteCubit() : super(authRouter);

  GoRouter get router {
    return state;
  }

  void login() {
    // then when login is triggered it will emit the appropriate route
    // on this I just use adminRoute for example
    emit(adminRoute);
  }
}

Then in my main.dart I use the BlockProvider on the main app.
void main() {
  usePathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(
    BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => RouteCubit(),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MaterialTheme theme = MaterialTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme);
    final ThemeData light = theme.lightHighContrast();
    final ThemeData dark = theme.darkHighContrast();

    return BlocBuilder<RouteCubit, GoRouter>(
      builder: (context, route) {
        return MaterialApp.router(
          // this is the part that will change the routes
          routerDelegate: route.routerDelegate,
          routeInformationParser: route.routeInformationParser,
          routeInformationProvider: route.routeInformationProvider,
          // routes setup end
          title: 'Health Information System',
          theme: light.copyWith(
            appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
              backgroundColor: light.colorScheme.inversePrimary,
            ),
          ),
          darkTheme: dark.copyWith(
            appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
              backgroundColor: dark.colorScheme.inversePrimary,
            ),
          ),
          themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


Then on the login screen I will just call the login of the RouteCubit.
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Bloc Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('Login Form'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // calling the login to change the route
                BlocProvider.of<RouteCubit>(context).login();
              },
              child: const Text('Login'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


